# linking extrenal javascript file inside head tag not working

Tags: javascript, html, dom

i have linked my script.js file to my index.html file and both files are in same directory. i have linked that script.js file in  section but that is not working when i open-up the console it is shwoing

```
script.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null
```

but whenever i link that file in the last part of the  section perfectly, even putting that file in the first section of  also not working.

inde.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sample</title>
</head>

<body>

    <p id="name">
        <span>john</span>
    </p>

</body>

</html>
```

script.js:

```
var result = document.getElementById("name");
var final = result.getElementsByTagName("span");
console.log(final);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: When you link javascript files in head, the won't see the dom elements rendered in body, thus your script won't see the `<p id="name">`. either put your code in `window.onload` or move it to the footer.

Comment: @Taplar then why in most of the examples they put that script.js file in <head>

Comment: Scripts can go in the head so long as the logic that tries to find elements in the DOM, happens after the DOM is loaded.

Comment: rashad-kokash whenever i put that <script> in last section of body section it is perfectly working but in many tutorials i have seen they are putting their <script> file in <head> and their code is perfectly working how??

Comment: As covered by the duplicate, the usage of a document ready or a load event handler on the window allows any logic to be put in the head, without having to worry about the DOM being loaded yet, as they delay the execution of the logic until the DOM is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scripts can go in the head so long as the logic that tries to find elements in the DOM, happens after the DOM is loaded.

As covered by the duplicate, the usage of a document ready or a load event handler on the window allows any logic to be put in the head, without having to worry about the DOM being loaded yet, as they delay the execution of the logic until the DOM is loaded.

Thank You @taplar